# initialize static var value from variable in Struct in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, initialization, structure, static-methods, static-variables

Im learning swift 3 and I have a question here

Sorry for wrong example..couldnt think of logical example

```
     enum Restaurant : String {
    case wendys = "wendy's"
    case chickfila = "chick fil'a"
    case subway = "SubWay"
}

public struct COMMON_INFO {

    var restaurant : Restaurant?
    public static let restaurant_zip: String?

    init(restaurant: Restaurant) {
        switch restaurant {
        case .wendys: break
            COMMON_INFO.restaurant_zip = "212345"
            self.restaurant = restaurant
        case .chickfila: break
            COMMON_INFO.restaurant_zip = "367849"
            self.restaurant = restaurant
        default: COMMON_INFO.restaurant_zip = "618374"
                 self.restaurant = restaurant
            break
        }
    }

    public static func getAddressFromZip() -> [String : Any] {

        let address = getAddressFrom(restaurant_zip)
        //do something with address
    }

    func getAddressFrom(zip:String) {
        //get address
    }

}
```

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjBaN.png)

I have an enum defined
I have a constant "restaurant_zip" defined in structure COMMON_INFO
I need to set the value of restaurant_zip depending on the value of variable restaurant

For that reason, i added an initializer and assigning value of static variable depending on case like shown in code

but i get error on line "public static let restaurant_zip: String?" -> "static var declaration requires an initializer expression"

my requirement is to have a static function getAddressFromZip in which i use static variable restaurant_zip" whose value is to be defined from initializer of struc COMMON_INFO

Please help me how to acheive this . Ive been trying but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get what you want, but using `var` instead might help:

```
public static var restaurant_zip: String?
```